# How to enable a the php_soap extension from .user.ini (no acces to php.ini)

Tags: php, web-hosting, godaddy, php.ini, plesk

Our application is being hosted on GoDaddy (plesk). We need to enable 'php_soap' extension for our application to work. We contacted the customer support that we don't have access to `php.ini` file to do so but they told us that we can use `.user.ini` instead.
We've tried doing that but `.user.ini` doesn't seem to enable `php_soap` extension when we added the line.

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

after testing if `.user.ini` works at all by changing another setting `upload_max_filesize` and it works. But enabling the `soap` extension doesn't work

Comment: You may be prohibited to load extensions in fact.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to ***serverfault*** **cominitutiy** .!

Try to create a php.ini file and add below line :

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

in some case it's commented so try to uncomment .

Also you can check the server extensions with creating a info.php file , So you should create a file name

> info.php

*However* you had to add this line to info.php file as well :

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Show just the module information.
// phpinfo(8) yields identical results.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>
```

**Finally** you should **restart** web server to load extension modules

Alternative contact your provider to help you out .

Have great day future **friend** . ;-)

Comment: I have no access to php.ini

Comment: I can only access .user.ini file which supposedly overrides `php.ini` but I can't get  it to enable the extension

Comment: try to create one php.ini file so far , also did you tried to create info.php i have provided above ?